# Disable GRUB setting itself to the first boot option on updates

Tags: grub2, bootloader, settings, refind

I use rEFInd as my bootloader, but I have ubuntu's kernel inside an lvm logic volume, so I use GRUB to call it from refind and boot ubuntu. But every time I update GRUB (via apt or update-grub) it sets itself as the first boot option, and I was wondering if there is any way of avoiding it, either editing some post-update or post-install hook or may be with some configuration option.

Thank you so much and sorry if I have been impolite, English it's not my native language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to patch `/usr/lib/grub/grub-multi-install` to add `--no-nvram` to the arguments of `grub-install`.  The `postinst` scripts for several packages call `grub-multi-install`.

I dug into this before on this Q: [How do I get grub-efi-amd64-signed to not automatically overwrite NVRAM on update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1256398/how-do-i-get-grub-efi-amd64-signed-to-not-automatically-overwrite-nvram-on-updat/1265390)